# Bluetooth not working on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS with ASUS X550LA

Tags: bluetooth, asus

I want to connect wireless Bluetooth speaker to my laptop, but unfortunately it wont see any bluetooth adapter.

Output of `rfkill list` is:

```
0: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```

Previously i had Windows installation and it worked there like a charm.
Maybe someone had similar issues with their Asus laptops.

Output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3` is:

```
03:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Ralink corp. RT3290 Wireless 802.11n 1T/1R PCIe [1814:3290]
    Subsystem: Foxconn International, Inc. RT3290 Wireless 802.11n 1T/1R PCIe [105b:e055]
    Kernel driver in use: rt2800pci
    Kernel modules: rt2800pci
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3; lsusb` terminal command.

Comment: edited the question with the new output of the command.

Comment: This device is poorly supported. You can replace it to something better. It is cheap.